# POI for XPages - save Word document as attachment in rich text field

Tags: java, apache-poi, xpages, lotus-notes

I'm using the OpenNTF POI 4 XPages plugin. This works very well for generating Word Documents. Now, after generating the Word document, I would like to create a new response document and store the word document as an attachment in a rich text field in this response document. Here is my code (in the poi postGenerationProcess property of the POI 4 XPages widget):

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
var rdoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
rdoc.appendItemValue("Form", "frmRespTempl");
rdoc.appendItemValue("Subject", "Embedded Word Document");
var rtitem:NotesRichTextItem = rdoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
rtitem.embedObject(xwpfdocument);
rdoc.makeResponse(doc);
rdoc.save();
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the error:

```
com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=13, 
col=8: [TypeError] Method NotesRichTextItem.embedObject(org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument)
not found, or illegal parameters
```

Any tips how I can achieve this?

Implementing the suggestion offered below by Knut Hermann, I get:

### POI 4 XPages -> ERROR

Error    : Error during Documentgeneration
POI LIB  : 1.2.6.201312211419
StackTrace:
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:126)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.containers.UIDocument$1.run(UIDocument.java:300)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.containers.UIDocument$1.run(UIDocument.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.containers.UIDocument.doPostGenerationProcessPrivileged(UIDocument.java:298)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.containers.UIDocument.postGenerationProcess(UIDocument.java:290)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.kernel.DocumentProcessor.processDocument(DocumentProcessor.java:233)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.kernel.DocumentProcessor.generateNewFile(DocumentProcessor.java:143)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.containers.UIDocument.processAjaxRequest(UIDocument.java:208)
    at biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.component.actions.DocumentGenerationServerAction.invoke(DocumentGenerationServerAction.java:48)
    at com.ibm.xsp.actions.ActionGroup.invoke(ActionGroup.java:135)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.broadcast(UIVarPublisherBase.java:183)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.broadcast(UIDataPanelBase.java:400)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:250)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:223)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:204)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:653)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:476)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=10, col=14: Error calling method 'write(java.io.FileOutputStream)' on java class 'org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument'
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:334)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:221)
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:141)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getContextTypeLoader(XmlBeans.java:336)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.PropertiesDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLProperties.(POIXMLProperties.java:75)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:139)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:108)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.getContextClassLoader(Thread.java:456)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl.getContextTypeLoader(SchemaTypeLoaderImpl.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor128.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getContextTypeLoader(XmlBeans.java:327)
    ... 62 more

Comment: rtitem.embedObject has to have at least three parameters: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_EMBEDOBJECT_METHOD_JAVA.html with the path to your Word file as the third. Write the Word file to file system and then you can attach it.

Answer (score 6):

Save your Word document to file system in a temporary folder and then attach it from there with `rtitem.embedObject` to your RichTextItem:

```
var temp = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
var file = new java.io.File(temp + "YourFile.docx"); 
var fileOutputStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
xwpfdocument.write(fileOutputStream);
fileOutputStream.close();

var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
var rdoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
rdoc.appendItemValue("Form", "frmRespTempl");
rdoc.appendItemValue("Subject", "Embedded Word Document");
var rtitem:RichTextItem = rdoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
rtitem.embedObject(lotus.domino.local.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "",
                   file.getAbsolutePath(), null);
rdoc.makeResponse(doc);
rdoc.save();
```

If you don't want to save the file into file system then create a MIMEEntity instead and stream the Word content direct to Notes document ([Java code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540635/2065611) as a starting point).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'm now trying to implement your solution but unfortunately I get an error:

Comment: I'm working on this issue now, I get the error com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=10, col=14: Error calling method 'write(java.io.FileOutputStream)' on java class 'org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument'
 at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:334)

Comment: Is there any additional information in stack trace about error cause?

Comment: Thanks, I just added the entire trace above.

Comment: I think the important part is "org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)" but what causes it?

Comment: Have you tried to grant all permissions in the java.policy (or java.pol) on the server ?

Comment: Just as a test: does it work if you change line `xwpfdocument.write(fileOutputStream);` to `fileOutputStream.write(1);` - this way we can test if writing files allowed.

Comment: Using the line fileOutputStream.write(1); writes a special character which looks like [] to the file.

Comment: You mean file got attached to Notes document and there was no error message?

Comment: Now a new response document is created which contains "YourFile.txt" in the Body field. YourFile is empty and the XPage displays the error message: Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

Comment: ok, the permission error comes from POI not from writing file to file system - I'll look at this this evening - error 500 is not relevant to  this issue

Comment: So, is it attempting to write to the user's machine or the server? I'm using the FacesContext to create spreadsheets, which presents the user with a dialog for where the file ought to go. I'm guessing that your method simply places it automatically and I'm wondering if the filepath is incorrect.

Comment: The file is created on the server in the C:\TempWord folder.

Comment: Yes, with java.lang.System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") the result is the same. A response doc is created with an empty .txt file.

Comment: (1) It will work if you add `grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };` to file `<server program dir>/jvm/lib/security/java.policy` and restart the http task. I had that on my dev server that's why it just worked for me. But, this is usually not an option for a production server for security reasons. That's why you might consider to realize one of the following comments.

Comment: (2) In source code of POI4XPages you can see that all original apache poi methods are framed by `AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<T>() {... poi methods ...}` to get the necessary rights at this moment (e.g. in biz.webgate.dominoext.poi.beans.PoiBean). You can use this technique in an own Java class to get the xwpfdocument.write() to work.

Comment: (3) If you use the `poiBean` to create the Word files then you can use the method `ByteArrayOutputStream processDocument2Stream()` and combine it with the MIMEEntity approach (see last part of my answer) OR add a method like `attachFile(String filename, RichTextItem rtitem)` to class PoiBean.

Comment: Thanks very much. Tip one works, I'll now try tip 2.

Comment: I'm trying to get point 2 to work now but I just can't get the syntax right :-(

Comment: "not the right syntax" means you can't compile the Java code or it doesn't run like expected?

Comment: I get the error 'processDocument2(java.io.FileOutputStream)' on java class 'AZGPackage.writeXWPFDocument' not found
 at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:360). I call the code from the postGenerationProcess event using var temp = java.lang.System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
var file = new java.io.File(temp + "YourFile.docx"); 
var fileOutputStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
var jce:writeXWPFDocument = new writeXWPFDocument();
jce.processDocument2(xwpfdocument,fileOutputStream); The method processDocument2 is contained in the java class below.

Comment: public FileOutputStream processDocument2(XWPFDocument xwpfdocument, FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) {
  
   final FileOutputStream fileOutputStreamFin = fileOutputStream;
   final XWPFDocument docFin;
   final FileOutputStream newdoc;
   docFin = xwpfdocument;
  
   newdoc = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<FileOutputStream>() {
    
    public FileOutputStream run() {
     try {
      docFin.write(fileOutputStreamFin);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return fileOutputStreamFin; 
    }
   });
   
   return fileOutputStreamFin;
  }

Comment: The error message tells that you call 'processDocument2(java.io.FileOutputStream)' with only one parameter but it is defined with two. In your code you call it with two parameters - is project not build after changing SSJS?

Comment: I have checked that the class is built but now get the error: Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=10, col=28: Java method 'processDocument2(org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument, java.io.FileOutputStream)' on java class 'AZGPackage.writeXWPFDocument' not found. Is the xwpfdocument available in the postGenerationProcess event actually an object of type org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument? I think I need to redefine the method so it will accept xwpfdocument being passed to it.

Comment: Is the Java class defined as a normal Design element in "Code / Java" or somewhere visible only in package explorer like "WebContent / ..."?

Comment: The java class is defined as a normal Java class design element in the .nsf

Comment: The java class is defined as a normal Java class design element under Code \ Java in the .nsf

Comment: If I define the method as public FileOutputStream processDocument2(Object xwpfdocument, FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) it is found but then the write method does not work.

Comment: I've now managed to pass the xwpfdocument as an XPWFDocument object. The problem was that the poi .jar files were installed on both the server and in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The Notes API requires a file, not a Java object. I would suggest you use the MIME document approach where you Base64 the Doc as mime part